# Spring Integration: Getting XSD Validation Error: cos-all-limited.1.2

Tags: spring, integration, xsd-validation

I am getting below XSD Valdation error on running Spring Integrtion code:

demo-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cos-all-limited.1.2: An ''all'' model group must appear in a particle with '{'min occurs'}'='{'max occurs'}'=1, and that particle must be part of a pair which constitutes the '{'content type'}' of a complex type definition.

demo-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd">

    <import resource="jdbc-context.xml" />

    <int:channel id="request" />
    <int:channel id="response" />

    <int:gateway id="demoService" service-interface="com.integration.DemoService" />

    <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway
        update="INSERT INTO Demo
                SELECT EID, BR from tab1, tab2
                WHERE tab1.BR=tab2.BR AND tab1.BR=:payload "

        request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel"
        data-source="dataSource" />

    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel"
        channel="responseChannel" expression="'Inserted successfully'" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your schema validator didn't like the schema -- but the schema looks OK to me (and more important, it looks OK Saxon, which is more reliable than I am on some details).

On the other hand, both Xerces and Saxon agree with your unnamed XSD validator that the document you show is invalid; they complain about the expression attribute on the int:logging-channel-adapter element and say that no attribute of that name is allowed.

Comment: The error is fixed after removing xercesImpl.jar from the classpath. But, I am still not very clear. How inclusion of xercesImpl.jar causing the exception? What if I need xercesImpl.jar in the classpath then how to fix it?